# My tyre has hollow knobs, is it normal/desirable/essential for maker to disclose?

Tags: tire, safety, frugal, wear

I noticed my back tyre has hollow knobs and I can't remember ever seeing this before. Some of the knobs have turned out to be hollow inside. I know YGWYPF, my questions are:

1. Is it normal? I got no meaningful results with google.
2. Is it desirable on a budget (even cheapskate really) tyre? It wouldn't
   surprise me on a £££ model, but in this case my guess would be that
   it would not meet the balance between extra cost of manufacturing
   complexities vs the savings on raw materials.
3. Shouldn't the label say the knobs are hollow? My loose thoughts
   would be that this has a bearing on a user's ability to assess
   things like performance and remaining life? Even if it's the
   subconscious visual assessment of these? I bought this in the UK but it's a global brand (and so is probably the model).

I'm aware many on here would argue this tyre is way overdue for replacement, this is not what the question is.

Edit: Clarification in response to some early comments.

- I can't tell for sure if this is a manufacturing defect, it might be, but I think this is part of my question really.
- The holes do not seem to go through the casing to the tube inside. The best way I can describe it is that it seems like they are hollow blocks/knobs glued onto a slick tyre. It also seems that the hollow space inside the hole is bigger that the opening that has been created.
- I estimate I've ridden 100 to 1000 km on this tyre, 95% tarmac (from dry to heavy rain), 5% well compacted gravel path, very little harsh braking. Estimates are very rough because I don't use any tracking and my cycling comes in irregular spells of commuting.
- They do indeed seem irregular. To me, this could equally indicate "unintended error in manufacturing" or "intended by design but poorly executed". The photos are a decent indication of the number and spread/distribution around the whole tyre. I'm fairly sure I didn't ride over enough broken glass (or similar) for that to be the main cause.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think the real question is if this is a manufacturing defect and if you have a right to a warranty replacement. To me it certainly looks as if they unintentionally trapped air/gas inside the knobs during the manufacturing process.

Comment: They seem irregular. Are you sure you didn't ride over some broken glass that has broken the surface/degraded the rubber?

Comment: The tire is worn well past its designed useable limit.

Comment: @mattnz Concur - 1000 km is a bit poor for any tyre.  Pateksan should replace it when it starts to puncture more or when grip is insufficient.  Perhaps choose another brand of tyre next time.

Comment: 1000 km from a knobbly mud tire on paved roads is actually quite a lot. The rubber compund is designed to stick to slippery roots, not last forever (can;t have both).  OP would be much better off buying a much less agressive tire more suited to paved roads.

Comment: Glas is most certainly not the cause. That would leave small cuts all over the place, not just in the center of the blocks. And a glass cut looks quite different to what you see. Anyways, if you are mostly riding on tarmac and well-compacted gravel, it's a good idea to opt for touring tires instead of mountain bike tires. They last longer, have less rolling resistance, and they are just the right tool for the job. As touring tires have a smaller profile, they should give you no trouble installing on a mountain bike.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the tread blocks are 'hollow' exactly.

Tires are made up of layers of different formulas of rubber. I think you have worn though the outer layer and a little chip of rubber has flaked out of the center of some of the the blocks. Now you can see that the next layer down has de-laminated from the outer a little, so it looks like there is a void there.

If the blocks are hollow, the void is only right at the bottom of the block, and would only be exposed if the tire is very well worn, as yours is.

Comment: I think I fully understand what you're suggesting up to "some of the the blocks". And then I totally don't get the last sentence. To me it seems that the "next layer down" is the main "body" of the tyre (shown as "tread" in diagram here: https://road.cc/content/feature/256210-beginners-guide-bicycle-tyres-everything-you-need-know-about-clinchers); and that "body" seems intact as far as I can tell. In other words, to me your answer makes perfect sense if I take it without that last sentence. Are you by any chance aware of a diagram which shows the layers so that we could refer to them clearly?

Comment: Ouch, you edited your answer (added the last paragraph) as I typed my comment. I'm sorry if I made it confusing for everyone.